# How do I change an ID to a Class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm unfamiliar with JavaScript and I've been trying to figure this out for days now and I just can't seem to get it to work.

I have this JSFiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/xslibx/nG4Zz/

HTML

```
<h4 id="tweet" >Some text here</h4>
<h4 id="tweet" >Some more text here</h4>
```

CSS

```
#tweet, #tweet_js { border:1px solid red; width:70px; padding:.5em; }
#tweet_js { overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap; }
.hiding { text-overflow:ellipsis; }
```

JavaScript

```
var tweet = document.getElementById('tweet');
tweet.id = 'tweet_js';
tweet.className = 'hiding';

var slide_timer,
    max = tweet.scrollWidth,
    slide = function () {
        tweet.scrollLeft += 1;
        if (tweet.scrollLeft < max) {
            slide_timer = setTimeout(slide, 40);
        }
    };

tweet.onmouseover = tweet.onmouseout = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e = e.type === 'mouseover';
    clearTimeout(slide_timer);
    tweet.className = e ? '' : 'hiding';
    if (e) {
        slide();
    } else {
        tweet.scrollLeft = 0;
    }
};
```

It is a scolling text effect for when the text is larger than the container the overflow is hidden. It is revieled when the mouse hovers over the text

this effect works for the first container but does not work for the second.

I have a feeling it's because it uses ID (#tweet, #tweet_js) instead of a CLASS (.tweet, .tweet_js). How would I change the JavaScript code so it works with classes instead of IDs

```
<h4 class="tweet" >Some text here</h4>
<h4 class="tweet" >Some more text here</h4>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I understand that, but how would I change the JavaScript code to work with classes instead?

Comment: This seems like something that needs to be fixed directly. You should never have multiple ID's that are the same name. Don't use Javascript to fix it.

Comment: You don't change the javascript code to fix it, you change the html source to fix it: `<h4 class="tweet">` or could give both a class and id: `<h4 class="tweet" id="t171">...</h4> <h4 class="tweet" id="t382">...</h4>`

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the duplicate IDs causing problems. An ID is supposed to be unique. Once you add more that one element with the same ID to a document, all bets are off.

In order to change your code, use `class="whatever"` in your markup, and access an array of matching elements using `document.getElementsByClassName("whatever")`.

**HTML:**

```
<h4 class="tweet" >Some text here</h4>
<h4 class="tweet" >Some more text here</h4>
```

**JS:**

```
var tweets = document.getElementsByClassName('tweet');

// Apply the hidden class to all tweets
for(var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
    tweets[i].classlist.add('hidden');
}

...
```

Comment: Just FYI not compatible with IE 8 or lower. See [here](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname)

Comment: @aug That is completely appalling. I would have guessed IE 7+ would have getElementsByClassName. There's always jQuery.

Comment: @Asad -- your code example has `getElementsById` where I think you meant `getElementsByClassName` like you wrote in the text.

Comment: @aug I usually take the approach of developing code for sane browsers, then progressively adding polyfills for things that are missing in weaker browsers. Sort of like teaching the browser to be the duck I need it to be.

Comment: @Asad OK I tried adding what you put, but the box still expands with the text, loosing the effect. I've saved my code in this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xslibx/9Et7y/
Sorry I'm a noob with JavaScript, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: The original JSFiddle is this http://jsfiddle.net/sdleihssirhc/AYYQe/3/
It can only apply to one element on a page I want it to apply to more than one per page

Comment: @xslibx Okay so regarding the first jsFiddle, could you please describe in words what your expected result is? I made some mistakes in my code but I think it would be helpful if I cleaned up other issues in the code simultaneously.

Comment: @xslibx Actually nevermind, I can see what you need from the second fiddle. I'll get back to you with a complete example in a bit.

Comment: @Asad I'll just restate my problem. I found this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sdleihssirhc/AYYQe/3/ The effect works when applied to only 1 element because it uses an ID (#tweet, and #tweet_js). I want this effect to work on more than 1 element per page, it would need to use a class instead of an id. So how would I write the JavaScript code so it effects the elements with class="tweet" ultimately allowing the effect to work multiple times on the same page?